# Bootstrap 4.3.1 - cannot disable validation icons

Tags: angular, sass, bootstrap-4

I've seen answers on S.O. regarding turning off Bootstrap validation icons. There are two answers:

1. $enable-validation-icons: false; (this is also recommended in
   bootstrap's theming docs)
2. Use SCSS/CSS to remove the    background-image.

I like the idea of simply setting a variable. And that works for changing the colors. But I cannot get it to work for the validation icons.

Here's how I'm setting variables and importing bootstrap from node_modules.

```css
$enable-validation-icons: false;  // <-- has no effect
$blue: #0F4F8C;  // <-- works as expected

@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
```

Do I need to do something extra within my scss file for the validation icons?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope. I just had to hide them using CSS. I got no responses here (obviously) nor on gitter. See my "resolution" below.

Answer (score 2):

I had to do a CSS hack to get rid of the icons. So I'll paste it here just in case anyone wants it. I put this in my main .scss file:

```css
// ******************************************
// *** handle bootstraps validation icons ***
// *** your's supposed to be able to set
// *** $enable-validation-icons: false; but
// *** that doesn't work for some reason ***
.form-control.is-valid {
    background-image: none;
}

.form-control.is-invalid {
    background-image: none;
    padding: $input-padding-y $input-padding-x;
}

.form-control-sm.is-valid {
    background-image: none;
}

.form-control-sm.is-invalid {
    background-image: none;
    padding: $input-padding-y-sm $input-padding-x-sm;
}

.form-control-lg.is-valid {
    background-image: none;
}

.form-control-lg.is-invalid {
    background-image: none;
    padding: $input-padding-y-lg $input-padding-x-lg;
}
// ******************************************
```